# How can I setup an alias in bash for "sudo vim (filename)" as sim (filename)

Tags: linux, bash, vim

What I normally type to edit a file is:

```
sudo vim Example.php
```

I'd like to type

```
sim Example.php
```

as a shortcut. I know I can setup an alias in the bash config file, but how do I go about specifying the argument in the alias? In this case the argument is the filename.

Answer (score 8):

Let me answer your question in several parts.

**Setting up an alias in Bash**

In your `.bashrc`, put a line that reads as follows:

```
alias sim="sudo vim"
```

On some systems (Ubuntu, for example), this line should instead go in your `.bash_aliases` file, which will automatically be loaded by your default `.bashrc`.

Note that it is not necessary to deal with the command arguments; these will be tacked onto the end of the `sudo vim` command automatically.

**Editing as superuser**

Take everything I just said and throw it out.

It is generally a better idea to use `sudoedit` instead. `sudoedit` will automatically make a temporary copy of the file that you can edit without superuser privileges. This means that vim will run as you (instead of as root), and only a brief moment of superuserity is needed after you're done editing the file.

**Making sure `sudoedit` runs vim**

On Debianish systems, use `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` to choose your preferred editor. Otherwise, make sure `$EDITOR` is set to vim in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: `export EDITOR=vim` is the line in `~/.bashrc` for Arch.

Answer (score 7):

You use `sudoedit Example.php` or `sudo -e Example.php` instead.  If that's invoking an editor other than Vim, then just add an `export EDITOR=vim` to your bash startup files.

As far as the alias is concerned, [jschmier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231169/how-can-i-setup-an-alias-in-bash-for-sudo-vim-filename-as-sim-filename/2231195#2231195) is correct.  Aliases are simply expanded and then any arguments are handled normally.  If you actually need to process arguments (instead of leaving them in place after the alias is expanded), you'll want to use a function.  See the bash documentation for [aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) and [functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions).

Comment: You should explain why this is better... that it doesn't run vi as root and let the user do lots of other bad-ness. I know this isn't what the user asked, but it is a much better answer to the apparent problem.

Comment: `export EDITOR=vim` is the line in `~/.bashrc` for Arch.

Answer (score 1):

`alias sim='sudo vim $1'`

Comment: Arguments aren't handled in aliases.  A function should be used if you need to handle arguments specially (i.e., not just use them exactly as they're given to the alias).

Comment: alias test='cat $1|grep config' works fine for me.

Comment: @bhups: `$1` is null and the filename is being passed as an command-line argument to `grep` (rather than through the pipe). So then `cat` is waiting for input from the terminal and you have to press Ctrl-D or Ctrl-C. Try something that does something to the file in the first step, like: `grep config $1 | tr c C`

Answer (score 1):

`alias sim='sudo vim'` and call as `sim Example.php`

Bash always reads at least one complete line of input before executing any of the commands on that line. Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.

See the [Aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) entry in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bash function instead. I have a function I use to show the last modification date of a file/folder:

```
function lm()
{
    ls -l "$*" | awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'
}
```

Try this:

```
function sim()
{
    sudo vim "$*"
}
```

The `$*` in bash represents all the command line arguments, i.e. everything after the name of the function.

Then use it like so: `$ sim -p Example.php Example2.php`

Answer (score 0):

not exactly answering the question but there is a nice trick to use when you started to edit the file and only then remembered that you forgot the sudo. you can use `:w !sudo tee %` to save the file with all your edits.